# Need regex to update my string (stored procedure call)

Tags: php, arrays, regex, string

I am have variables bellow:

```
$array1=(array('in1', 1), array ('in2', 1));
$array2=(array('inout1', 2));
$array3=(array('out1', 5), array ('out2', 5));
```

Note: count of all three arrays = **5**;

```
$sp_name='myProc';
```

I get above three arrays from some functions etc. It has to be like that.

What I need to get from above array is a string below:

```
$sql='{call myProc(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)}';
```

I was thinking about some regex that would add (?, ? ..., ?) ... depending on number of elements of three dynamic arrays. In my example 5 question marks.

Also I need to merge all three arrays in one `$array_merged(array(some_col, some_int), array( ....));`

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: I figured out how to merge arrays (`array_merge()`) ...

Comment: why not `array_fill`?

Comment: I have arrays and need to merge them. Would array_fill be better choice? array_merge does it too ... not sure what is your point here but thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to use regex also, but it is not necessary at all:

```
<?php

$array1 = array(array('in1', 1), array('in2', 1));
$array2 = array(array('inout1', 2));
$array3 = array(array('out1', 5), array('out2', 5));

$array_merged = array_merge($array1, $array2, $array3);

$sql = '{call myProc(' . implode(', ', array_fill(0, count($array_merged), '?')) . ')}';

echo '<pre>';
print_r($array_merged);
echo '</pre>';

echo $sql;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can build a string using a loop

```
$array = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5',];

$string = ''; // create empty string variable

// loop and build string
foreach($array as $value){
    $string = $string . '?,';
}

$string = rtrim($string,','); // remove last comma

echo $string;
// prints ?,?,?,?,?
```

Comment: This would work ... However, I somehow wanted regex. Does it make sense? Will up-vote for your effort...

Comment: So you want regex to replace all values in an array with `?,`

Comment: No, I want the same output that you produced with your answer above. So depending on a number of elements in merged array (my example has 5 elements) I just want to get that many ?, ... Again, your code above already produces that... Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that. The problem is, using `preg_replace()` with an array, you need the regex patter and the replacements to both be arrays, therefore you are going to need a loop either way I believe.